# Is there any index to be used to get transaction history for a certain-aggregate Id?

Tags: transactions, event, history

I was wondering if EOS blockchain could be used as event-store for event-sourcing. At least, we should be able to retrieve history with an aggregate id. Of course, we can use the EOS account name as an aggregate id, but domains with numerous aggregates can not afford resource(RAM) costs. Is there any solution for this?